# How to integrate Linkedin Login in iOS Without SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linkedin-api

In iOS most of them integrated LinkedIn Login via SDK(if LinkedIn App is not installed in your iPhone/iPad you cant login, LinkedIn SDK return a message to install LinkedIn App).

But during Apple Review, there may be a chance to reject our app.
So the only solution is to handle two situation.

1.LinkedIn Login With SDK

2.LinkedIn Login without SDK ( Using OAuth 2.0)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

First you need to check LinkedIn App is installed or not in your iPhone/iPad.

```
isInstalled("linkedin://app") // function call


func isInstalled(appScheme:String) -> Bool{
    let appUrl = NSURL(string: appScheme)

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(appUrl! as NSURL)
    {
        return true

    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

**Step 2**

Create a webviewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    let linkedInKey = "xxxxxx"

    let linkedInSecret = "xxxxxx"

    let authorizationEndPoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"

    let accessTokenEndPoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        self.startAuthorization()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func startAuthorization() {
        let responseType = "code"
        let redirectURL = "https://com.appcoda.linkedin.oauth/oauth".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet())!

        let state = "linkedin\(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))"

        let scope = "r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress"

        var authorizationURL = "\(authorizationEndPoint)?"
        authorizationURL += "response_type=\(responseType)&"
        authorizationURL += "client_id=\(linkedInKey)&"
        authorizationURL += "redirect_uri=\(redirectURL)&"
        authorizationURL += "state=\(state)&"
        authorizationURL += "scope=\(scope)"

        // logout already logined user or revoke tokens
        logout()

        // Create a URL request and load it in the web view.
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: authorizationURL)!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)


    }

    func logout(){
        let revokeUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken"
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: revokeUrl)!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let url = request.URL!
        if url.host == "com.appcoda.linkedin.oauth" {
            if url.absoluteString!.rangeOfString("code") != nil {
                let urlParts = url.absoluteString!.componentsSeparatedByString("?")
                let code = urlParts[1].componentsSeparatedByString("=")[1]

                requestForAccessToken(code)
            }

        }

        return true
    }
    func requestForAccessToken(authorizationCode: String) {
        let grantType = "authorization_code"

        let redirectURL = "https://com.appcoda.linkedin.oauth/oauth".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet())!


        // Set the POST parameters.
        var postParams = "grant_type=\(grantType)&"
        postParams += "code=\(authorizationCode)&"
        postParams += "redirect_uri=\(redirectURL)&"
        postParams += "client_id=\(linkedInKey)&"
        postParams += "client_secret=\(linkedInSecret)"


        // Convert the POST parameters into a NSData object.
        let postData = postParams.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        // Initialize a mutable URL request object using the access token endpoint URL string.
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: accessTokenEndPoint)!)

        // Indicate that we're about to make a POST request.
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // Set the HTTP body using the postData object created above.
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        // Add the required HTTP header field.
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Initialize a NSURLSession object.
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

        // Make the request.
        let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Get the HTTP status code of the request.
            let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {
                // Convert the received JSON data into a dictionary.
                do {
                    let dataDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                    print("dataDictionary\(dataDictionary)")
                    let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! String

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                    print("START sentData")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


       self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

                    })
                }
                catch {
                    print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
                }
            }else{
                print("cancel clicked")
            }
        }

        task.resume() 
    }  
    }
```

**Step 3**

LinkedIn login Button Click

```
  @IBAction func linkedinButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (self.isInstalled("linkedin://app")){
        // App installed
        let permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION]
           print("persmission end")
        LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth(permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
            let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session


            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,public-profile-url,industry,positions,location)?format=json", success: { (response) -> Void in

            if let data = response.data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                if let dictResponse = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers){
                  print("success")
                }
            }
            }, error: { (error) -> Void in
                        print("LINKEDIN error\(error)")

                     })

        }) { (error) -> Void in
             print("error login linkedin")

          }
    }else{
        // App not installed
        print("App is not installed")
        isBackFromWebViewCntr = true
        let webViewCnt = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WebViewController") as UIViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewCnt, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: hi @eldhose did you any pod or sdk if yes can you give me  link of that

Comment: I have two login method
 1. LinkedIn Login With SDK
 
 2. LinkedIn Login without SDK ( Using OAuth 2.0)

For the first method, I'm using Linkedin SDK in my app. for the second method, we not need any SDK or Pod file.

Comment: I want to login using that and get some basic profile details lie email name ,link,If app is installed in the phone it should open the app and get details r else it should open in webview and get me details, which method i have to fllow

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu You want details like email, name, link etc.... You can choose any one of the method. I chose, because if the user doesn't installed LinkedIn App. In that case, we need details. So we get that details through  API.

Comment: Benefits of LinkedIn SDK is User not need to log in again, if the user is already login in the LinkedIn app. And drawback is Linkedin SDK increase app size.

Comment: I am using same code which you have given above i am going to navigation web page i am giving details in when i click on login it just stays their

Comment: when i click on login LinkedIn in webpage i am getting CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "Password Protected Area";
    srvr = "jobz.com";
    sync = syna;
}
if you want i can send you the project

Comment: you can check my code  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640774/integrating-linkedin-in-ios-app-for-getting-some-details

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that even LinkedIn is not providing a documentation or a sample project for this problem, I went through so many web pages and finally found something useful in this [link](https://www.elsner.com/linkedin-sign-in-using-oauth-2-0-update-on-ios-apps/). This website provides both tutorial and sample [code](https://github.com/elsnertechno/LinkedInSignInSwift). Download the sample code and replace following values generated in your LinkedIn developer portal

```
let linkedInKey = "your LinkedIn key"
let linkedInSecret = "your LinkedIn secret"
let callBackURL = "your callback url"
```

In WKNavigationDelegate replace the host url with your host url (in my case its my callback url without "https://")

```
request.url?.host == "com.elsner.linkedin.oauth" // Change this to

request.url?.host == "your callback url's host"
```

Comment: initially then given the support,,,i think,,now the stoped SDK support